# Databricks does not recognize all Oracle transformations

Tags: python, sql, oracle, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to make a conversion from Oracle to Databricks, nothing complex, the data is of the string type ('24 -MAR-11 ') and I am trying to change it to a date type to transform it back to another format ('24 -03-2011') , but I've been trying to find the sentence according to the documentation for a while and I can't find what I'm looking for.

Among the alternatives that I have tried are the following:

```
date_format('24-MAR-11' as 'DD-MON-YY')
to_date('24-MAR-11', 'dd-MON-yy')
cast('24-MAR-11', date)
cast('24-MAR-11', 'dd-MON-yy')
```

In Oracle that works, in Databricks it doesn't.

Please recommend me any method?

Thank you very much in advance, I will be attentive to your comments!

Regards!!

Comment: I don't know Databricks, but I'd take a wild guess at SQL Server syntax. How about `TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, '24-MAR-11', 106)` http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server/to_date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the functions `to_date` (which converts a string to a date with an optional date format string), and `date_format`, which formats a date in the given format string to achieve what you want.  The mistake in your code is, the input string for `to_date` should be in the format of your input string, not the format you want the string to be, ie

```
%py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([("24 Mar 11",)], ["xdate"])

df.withColumn("xdate1", to_date("xdate", "dd MMM yy")).show()

df.withColumn("xdate2", date_format( to_date("xdate", "dd MMM yy"), "dd-MM-yyyy")).show()
```

NB in my first call to to_date I am using the format string `dd MMM yy` which is the format of your input string `24 Mar 11`.  The second call with `date_format` then displays the string in the desired format.  My results:

[image]

Comment: sorry for my delay in answering @wBob, thank you very much !! exactly that function I was looking for, thank you very much for your support, I really appreciate it! :)